# On Premises Reporting Services won't connect to SQL Azure databaes

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a Reporting Services report that connects to an Azure SQL database.

The data-source creates and tests successfully:

[image]

[image]

But when I try to create an associated data-set I get the following error. Has anyone seen this before, and knows how to fix it?

I can connect to the instance just fine through Management Studio.

Comment: I was wondering about the connection string, have you specified the initial catalog?

Comment: Thanks for your response Lin. Yes I have.

Answer (score 0):

On a second test, i was able to reproduce it when i start typing un-recognized connection string parameters(random characters) in the connection string field of data source. You need to double check your connection string.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for that Lin. I double checked that and I don't have any random characters at the end of my connection string :(